# How to prevent the CSS `:before` text being editable while the `div` itself is editable?

Tags: css, firefox

I have an editable body with a `div`:

```
<body contenteditable="true">
    <div class="paragraph">Text</div>
<body/>
```

And a `:before` style:

```
div.paragraph:before {
    content: "☑";
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uy9xs5p0/

In Firefox I can put the cursor at the beginning of the text and press backspace and the check mark gets deleted. How to prevent that?

Comment: Are you able to modify your html?

Comment: This is an odd and interesting case. Have you tried to use the (Mozilla-specific) [-moz-user-modify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-user-modify) on the `:before`?

Comment: Hm, seems not to work: http://jsfiddle.net/eezsgc62/

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome, too: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5y00q6ya/, and I'm stunned that this is possible, given the generated content isn't (supposed to be?) in the DOM.

Comment: @DavidThomas [status-norepro] here in Chrome.

Comment: @David Thomas: It seems in Chrome you can remove the generated content *only* when the main content is empty. In Firefox you can remove the generated content at any time

Comment: No, not in my case (Chrome 40.0.2214.94 m/ Windows 8.1); the `::before` can be deleted, regardless of the `div.paragraph` being empty or with content.

Comment: @David Thomas: Mine is the exact same version but on Windows 7. Never change, Chrome.

Comment: Not sure it is bug though. The [editing API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#the-delete-command) describes that a merge occurs (*although not sure of the rules of the merge*)

Comment: @BoltClock: Chrome: fuelling rage since 2009 (released in the previous year, but not truly irritating for a little while post-release).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are setting the `contenteditable` in the parent div, therefore when erasing, you are deleting the `div.paragraph`, so the pseudo will be gone.

See that if you set the property in the child div instead, you can make it work.

```css
div.paragraph:before {
    content: "☑";
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div contenteditable="true" class="paragraph">Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

When this issue is reproduced, (via [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5y00q6ya/1/), for instance) the developer tools show that `div.paragraph` is removed. Only a text node remains.

[image]

becomes

[image]
To stop the div from being removed, don't give its parent `contenteditable`. Use this instead:

```
<body>
    <div class="paragraph" contenteditable="true">Text</div>
</body>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5y00q6ya/3/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You answered 2m before the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are not editing the `:before` content.

It just removes the whole `.paragraph` element once it gets empty, or if you backspace when you are at the beginning of the tag.

Comment: In firefox it doesn't have to be empty, he can remove the tick

Comment: The text "Text" is still there after the before text has been removed.

Comment: Yes, but it does not remove the content of `:before`, it removes the wrapped div.

Comment: OK I see it in Firefox inspector.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers explain the problem. If a `div` inherits its edit-ability from its parent, it is possible to remove the child `div` itself and together with the `div` also the before-content.

In order to prevent this, it is necessary that the editable `div` must not be placed in an editable parent. This makes it necessary to put every editable `div` into a non editable parent `div` to preserve the editable child `div`.

The following example shows this

```css
div.node {
    margin-left: 1em;
}

div.paragraph:before {
    content: "☑";
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="false" class="node">
    <div contenteditable="true" class="paragraph">Major</div>
    <div contenteditable="false" class="node">
        <div contenteditable="true" class="paragraph">Minor</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround this problem. This seems to working as you want it to be.

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="upper-div">
    <div class="paragraph">Text</div>
</div>

div.upper-div:before {
    content: "☑";
    display:inline-block;
}
.paragraph{display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: Your suggestion moves the check mark to the outer body. I need the check mark on each div, not just one for the body.